# How to handle empty respons of this.store.find('product', id) in emberjs?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, store, promise

In emberjs I have a `/product/:product_id` dynamic route which renders `product` template backed by model hook of `ProductRoute` and `ProductController` as expected.

`this.store.find('product', id)` uses RESTAdapter and gives me a response (which follows JSON Conventions for RESTAdapter) as : `{product: {"id":"1","name":"prod1"}}` and renders the template as expected when product is found. But when the product is empty (not found in database), I get the response as : `{product: {}}`. Now I am unable to figure out the way to intercept the response and check for empty dict, and give proper alert message (something like 'Product with given ID not found').

Note: The `promise` returned by `this.store.find` becomes an `Ember Object of type product` once resolved.

Ember's error message when no product is found : `You must include an`id`in a hash passed to 'push'`

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

An empty request is telling Ember-Data that the request was successful even though it wasn't. Your server should be responding with a 404 when the product isn't found, not an empty request. Otherwise, Ember-Data is going to assume that the empty object *is* the product.

Comment: Hi GJK. Thanks a lot for your help. Actually I have written a server in such a way that it returns `{product: {}}` when no product is found. Even my server's response for `/products` is `{product: []}` if there is no product in the database. Can I deal with such situation at the front-end itself (without changing my server's response) ?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend it, but you could. The easiest way would be to write your own adapter and reject the promise when you get an empty response.

Comment: Okay. Thanks a lot. I will look into it (apparently changing server code would be a lot easier for me !)